# LTspice G source in latex

Tags: circuitikz

I was wondering if it is possible to draw this G source
[image]

in latex and the eventual corresponding code.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try something with [CircuiTikZ](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/circuitikz) for example.

Comment: @projetmbc but I don't know which symbol

Comment: Try something and then we will help you. We need a M(not)WE, that is a Minimal (not) Working Example.

Comment: We can see your symbol (Voltage Controlled Currant Source) better at this question: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/335686/how-to-put-in-voltage-dependent-current-source-in-ltspice. But the normalized symbols (lozenge shape) are displayed here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Current_source (figure 2). These symbols are on the circuitikz manual at section 4.5.4 Controlled sources. For the LTspice symbol, you need to define your own component (section 9 of the manual). I don't have the skill for this.

Comment: @quark67 Thank you! Your answer is exactly what I needed!